# Several problems with file uploading in PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am new to PHP. Currently I am learning how to do PHP file upload validation and following an implementation proposed in https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

I created a HTML file upload form, send a POST request to process.php then if it passed the validation check, server will redirect to another page called file.php containing the link of the uploaded file for downloading.

Here is my code:
process.php

```
<?php

try {
    if (!isset($_FILES['file']['error']) || is_array($_FILES['file']['error'])) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid parameters.");
    }

    switch ($_FILES['file']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            break;
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            throw new RuntimeException("No file uploaded.");
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            throw new RuntimeException("File size exceeded the limit.");
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown errors.");
    }

    if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 3 * 1024 * 1024) {
        //exceeded 3 MB
        throw new RuntimeException("File size exceeded the limit.");
    }

    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    if (false === $ext = array_search(
        $finfo->file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']),
        array(
            'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
            'png' => 'image/png',
            'gif' => 'image/gif',
        ),
        true
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException("File type not allowed.");
    }

    $destpath = __DIR__ . "/" . sprintf("uploads/%s.%s", sha1_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), $ext);
    if (!move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
        $destpath
    )) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to move uploaded file.");
    }

    header("Location: file.php");
    exit();
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

file.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include "process.php";
    ?>
    <p><?php $destpath;?></p><br>
    <a href="<?php $destpath;?>">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are some problems:

1. The $destpath in file.php is supposed to contain the file path ($destpath is a variable in process.php, which I included in file.php) but it appears to be a variable containing nothing.
2. After `header("Location: file.php)` I called `exit()` method, but the "Invalid parameters." message still displayed. I don't know why it passed all validation check (because it redirected to file.php successfully) but it still displayed that message (which is for the first check). Also I called `exit()` but the `echo $e->getMessage()` in the catch block still got executed.
3. I created `uploads` folder in terminal, and the folder had the privilege 755. I have to change it to 777 in terminal so `move_uploaded_file()` in process.php can work properly (maybe because the scripts are executed by XAMPP, which is not the owner of the folder). Is there any common practice for this uploading procedure? Because the folder with 777 privilege is insecure, I want it to be 755 and the `move_uploaded_file()` still works. Currently I am using XAMPP on MacOS.

I am new to PHP, please bear with me. Thank you!

Comment: Using the `Location` header tells the client to perform a secondary GET request to the value provided

Comment: The validation check is in process.php, the GET request is sent to file.php, so there should not be message printed out. Or maybe because in file.php I included process.php so that's why it printed out the message?

Comment: _"in file.php I included process.php so that's why it printed out the message"_... yes, this